# WCF Self-Hosted ServiceHost Error with Multiple IP Addresses

Tags: web-services, wcf, self-hosting, servicehost

I'm self-hosting a web service using WCF. The host computer has multiple ethernet ports, so I am creating the ServiceHost with multiple URIs. When I create the service host, I get the following error:

"This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. 
Parameter name: item"

Following is the code:

```
Uri[] uriSet = new Uri[ipList.Count];
for (int i=0; i<ipList.Count; i++)
{
    string baseAddress = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/mynamespace", ipList[i], myport);
    uriSet[i] = new Uri(baseAddress);
}

host = new ServiceHost(webServiceType, uriSet);
```

ipList contains the list of IP addresses for the host computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special IP address 0.0.0.0 or just localhost to match any IP address for the local machine.  Therefore, you should only need one base address URI, with either `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`.

```
host = new ServiceHost(webServiceType, new Uri[] { new Uri("http://localhost:80/mynamespace") });
```

or

```
host = new ServiceHost(webServiceType, new Uri[] { new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:80/mynamespace") });
```

* where 80 is the port.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have tried both of these. These work as far as the web service goes. When a user gets the published WSDL from the server, the addresses in the WSDL are either 0 or localhost. There are 2 XSD references in the WSDL and these do not work when directly connecting to the server to create the web client.

Comment: The WSDL has the following references in it:   <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://oldi.tmanager/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:9500/mynamespace?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://mynamespace" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:9500/mynamespace?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>

Comment: These references don't work for creating the web client because of the reference to localhost. They do work if the IP is in the definition.

Comment: Looks like there is some code around to flatten the WSDL into a single file. This would probably work. I'll give it a try...

Comment: I was able to flatten the WSDL. It works better now. There are no XSD files. However, in the WSDL the service port refers to localhost and this causes apps that connect directly to the server to have a problem connecting. Seems to me like a problem with the app since the app really knows what the correct IP is, but it uses the WSDL without substituting the correct IP in the port section.

Comment: I tend to agree that if the application developer knows the address of the service to get the WSDL, then they should be able to substitute the address for the one reflected in the WSDL.  AFAIK setting the address is common practice